# AWS - Allow other Account to read and decrypt DynamoDB data with KMS (Java)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kms

I have an account A, which has a DynamoDB Table with the contents encrypted using a KMS key, also in account A.

I want to give access to account B so that it is able to read DynamoDB data and decrypt it using the same KMS key.

### First Step: DynamoDB Access Across Accounts

I used this article: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html.

- Created a Role in Account A which specifies Account B's IAM user as the trusted entity
- Created an IAM User in Account B which has AssumeRole policy to access the role in Account A
- For the code that runs in the context of Account B, created DynamoDBMapper which uses the STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider for assuming the role

```java
AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient = 
        AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.builder()
                .withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider)
                .withRegion(dynamoRegion)
                .build();
STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider arscp =
        new STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider.Builder(accessRole, accessRoleName)
                .withStsClient(stsClient)
                .build();
AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
        .withRegion(dynamoRegion)
        .withCredentials(arscp)
        .build();
```

This works!

### Second Step: Using KMS to Encrypt/Decrypt Data (not cross-account)

Used the [aws-dynamodb-encryption-java](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-dynamodb-encryption-java) library for that. While creating DynamoDBMapper, pass in the AttributeEncryptor derived from KMS Material Provider:

```java
AWSKMS kms = AWSKMSClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(region)
                .withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider)
                .build();
EncryptionMaterialsProvider encryptionProvider = new DirectKmsMaterialProvider(kms, keyId);
return new DynamoDBMapper(client, dynamoDBMapperConfig, new AttributeEncryptor(encryptionProvider));
```

This also works!

### Third Step: Allowing Account B to decrypt data from DynamoDB

Followed this article: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policy-modifying.html#key-policy-modifying-external-accounts

- Modified the Key policy in Account A to give access to root of Account B
- Created an IAM policy in Account B to have the appropriate permissions to be able to access the KMS key in Account A.

From code perspective, I am using the same code as in second step to create the AWSKMS instance, albeit with the IAM policy created in Step 3. I get the following error:

```
com.amazonaws.services.kms.model.NotFoundException: Key 'arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:<Account B>:key/<KMS Key Id>' does not exist
```

Why is trying to look for the key in Account B? Is it because I need to Assume Role to access the KMS key as well? But the documentation doesn't speak about that. Also, I have not created any IAM Policy in Account B to assume role for KMS.

Any pointers appreciated.